# After explode function cannot insert all rows to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

**users:**

```
user_id (int, auto increment, primary key)
username (varchar (100))
(the rest is not immportant)
```

**teams:**

```
team_id(int, auto increment, primary key)
teamname (varchar (100))
(the rest is not important)
```

**team_users:**

```
team_id int, 
user_id int,
primary key (team_id, user_id),
foreign key (team_id) references teams (team_id),
foreign key (user_id) references users (user_id)
```

I have a form in which a user can create a team and can also add member names, which are going to be comma separated values.

What I would like is to insert the team details into the team table and the member names,  after using explode and finding their matching user_ids in users table, insert into team_users together with the last created team id.

What I have so far is this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

if (!$conn) {
    die("connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$teamname = $_POST['teamname'];
$members = $_POST['members'];
$games = $_POST['games'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO teams (teamname, games, images, founded) VALUES ('$teamname', '$games', '$image', NOW())");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

if(!empty($id)) {
    $membernames = explode(',', $members);    
    foreach($membernames as $value) { 

        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into team_users (team_id, user_id)
        select teams.team_id, users.user_id
        from teams, users where users.username = '$value' and teams.team_id = '$id'");

    } 

    if(false === $sql) die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

My problem is that when I execute this, it inserts only one, the first added user's id into team_users, however a user can add more than one users to be a member of a team. Why am I doing wrong?

I've created a username column in team_users table and instead deleted user_id and changed the query (insert into team_users (team_id, username) values ('$id', '$value') to see if it would insert all member names and it does. But I don't need their usernames in team_users table, I'd need their user_id.

I'm very new to PHP and Mysql and I've read a lot of forums and similar questions but couldn't find the answer. I'm stucked on this since days, can someone please help? Thank you so mucH!

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['members']`? Can you also paste your HTML?

Comment: Try adding this as the first line inside your `foreach` loop. `$value = trim($value);`

Comment: It worked perfectly ! You saved my day,  thank you so so much! Can you please explain why? I thought trim is for removing white space and other predefined characters. How does trim help in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this as the first line inside your `foreach` loop.

`$value = trim($value);`

This is because, when you explode the comma separated string, there is high chance that white spaces may get added to it.

For e.g. When we write a comma separated string `"Adam, Eve, William"`, notice the space after each comma. So when you explode with comma, the array will have `Adam`, `<space>Eve`, `<space>William`

So in your query only `Adam` works since `Eve` and `William` has a blank space added at the beginning.

When you trim, the spaces are removed. Hope this explains.

Comment: Yes, it's all clear now. Thank you for the explanation!